# Testing for key in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to create a bot for an MMO called "Graal Online Classic" with Pyautogui. It would read the "PM" of a player who messages them, then reply with the appropriate response. It would also take a screenshot of the players name, converts it to a string with tesseract, and store it in a dictionary(and also store where that particular player is in the bot's response hierarchy) and use that to determine if the player had messaged them before.

```
def player_id(name_coords, option): # Indentifies person who messaged and depending on if this person has messaged before changes response
    players = {} # Used to store players names and where in the response is
    keys = players.keys()

    image = pyautogui.screenshot('name_test.png', region = name_coords) # Names are screenshots 
    name_image = str(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('name_test.png')))
    print(name_image)
    for name_image in keys:
        print("User is previous user.")
        if players[name_image] == None:
            players[name_image] = option
        else:
            players[name_image] = players[name_image] + option
        return players[name_image]
    else:
        print("User was not previously found, adding to dictionary.")
        players[name_image] = None
        print(players.keys())
        print(players)
```

The problem stems with the function above. When it finds a person who has messaged them before, should go to the if statement, but no matter what, the else statement will execute instead. I print the values in players and its the same when the player messages them a second time but  for name_image in keys: still returns false.

Here is the full code if needed https://pastebin.com/haJRfqJD

Here is the log of the program running for 3 messages

```
None
(454, 222)
Found a waiting message
Found an open message
1003 424
Player messaged 1
1
I hate sand
User was not previously found, adding to dictionary.
dict_keys(['I hate sand'])
{'I hate sand': None}
The bounty quest allows you to hunt mobs for cash! Location: Castle, steward's room(to the right in the throne room) [PM 1 for specifics, PM 2 for TIPS, PM 3 for possible bounties]
Replying...
(454, 222)
Found a waiting message
Found an open message
1003 424
Player messaged 1
1
I hate sand
User was not previously found, adding to dictionary.
dict_keys(['I hate sand'])
{'I hate sand': None}
The bounty quest allows you to hunt mobs for cash! Location: Castle, steward's room(to the right in the throne room) [PM 1 for specifics, PM 2 for TIPS, PM 3 for possible bounties]
Replying...
(454, 222)
Found a waiting message
Found an open message
1003 424
Player messaged 1
1
I hate sand
User was not previously found, adding to dictionary.
dict_keys(['I hate sand'])
{'I hate sand': None}
The bounty quest allows you to hunt mobs for cash! Location: Castle, steward's room(to the right in the throne room) [PM 1 for specifics, PM 2 for TIPS, PM 3 for possible bounties]
Replying...
```

Comment: If you're checking for the existence of a key use `if not name_image in players:`.

Comment: `name_image` is taken from `players.keys()`. Under what circumstances is it linked to the value `None`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a for loop here. That's the whole point of using a dictionary - to avoid an expensive O(N) lookup. Dictionary look ups are fast. Replace your for loop with

```
name = players.get(name_image)
if name:    
    # your variable naming is totally unclear. I **think** this is what you want
    players[name] = option
    return players[name]
else:
    print("User was not previously found, adding to dictionary.")
    players[name_image] = None
    print(players.keys())
    print(players)
```

Note that in your original cdoe, you are defining a name_image as follows:

```
name_image = str(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('name_test.png')))
```

But that variable get's over written in the for loop.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it seems that    if name: just doesnt wanna execute. Here is the log from when I send myself 3 messages with the same name. CANT FIND DIGIT ANSWER I hate sand
User was not previously found, adding to dictionary.
dict_keys(['I hate sand'])
{'I hate sand': None}
 None
I hate sand
User was not previously found, adding to dictionary.
dict_keys(['I hate sand'])
{'I hate sand': None} I cant really post the entire log due to the character limit but as you can see from the above the if statement doesn't execute even when the value should be in the dictionary.

Comment: I replied too early, please check again.

Comment: Added log to main post.

Comment: See the update to the answer. As mentioned. your `name_image` variable is heavily abused. It's upto you to figure out which variable belongs where. This answer, addresses the original question you posted.